# MongoDB - Java - what is Easiest way to combine logical OR and logical AND?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following query as an example:
year = 2012 OR year = 2011 AND name = John OR name = Mike AND county = USA OR country = Canada

What is the best way to construct this using the JAVA driver?
Using the DBObject is a bit tricky as it's actually a Map so keys have to be distinct.
I could not find a decent example with QueryBuilder either (i.e. one using a loop).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$in` operator instead of `$or` for this.  I'm not familiar with the Java driver, but your query object should look like this:

```
{
    year: { $in: [2012, 2011] },
    name: { $in: ['John', 'Mike'] },
    country: { $in: ['USA', 'Canada'] }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not think about the $in option, works like a charm!